# VBScript to uninstall software

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to get a VBScript to uninstall software. When I run it, it seems to only process the first hit and then end. What do I have wrong that it's not looping through every instance of sMatch in strPublisher?

```
sMatch = "Mitel Networks Corporation"
On Error Resume Next
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
oReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubKeys
For Each subkey In arrSubKeys
   strPublisher = ""
   strPublisher = WshShell.RegRead ("HKLM\" & strKeyPath & "\" & subkey & "\Publisher")
   If InStr(1, strPublisher, sMatch) >0 Then
      WshShell.Run "cmd /c C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe /X" & SubKey & " /L*V msilog.txt", 1, True
      WScript.Sleep 50000
   End If
Next
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

comment out the:
    on error resume next
and you might get an error leading to the issue. What error do you get?